# Why aren't birthdays celebrated in Fire Force? And what is Hika and Hina's birthday?

Tags: fire-force

So I noticed that none of the characters' birthdays are celebrated, nor do we know when Shinra came to join the 8th, and we haven't really seen seasons change, (well also there's little no vegetation except in where Vulcan lived) so it's hard to tell the passing of time.

I'd like to know kind of where on the calendar this whole thing started, and I'm kinda curious why 8th wouldn't celebrate each others' birthdays.  I know it's not important and/or something they just don't show.  By the whole thing, I mean the start of the anime with Shinra in the first episode.

Lastly we don't get any information on when Hika and Hina were born.

Comment: It's pretty common in fiction for characters to not celebrate their birthday despite having one listed. Ash Ketchum is famously still 10 after over 25 years of adventures. Things like birthdays, blood types, favourite foods, etc. are things that contribute to the world building of a piece, making the characters feel more lifelike. The thing is suspension of disbelief counterbalances the need for these little quirks that don't matter to the plot. We never see the 8th celebrate birthdays, nor pay taxes, nor take out the trash but we don't need it to buy into the fiction

Comment: @Gatchwar:  Counter example:  Ash *did* celebrate his birthday [in the movie short *Pikachu & Pichu*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/PK07) released as a part of the third movie.  (Note: the day that Ash turned 10 was also the day he received Pikachu.)